# Multiple try statements; returning to the corresponding try statement instead of the first input

Tags: python

I am trying to get the program to loop back to the second try statement when the user correctly inputs a number for the first input but does not for the second input. 
The code:

```
print ("We're gonna be doing some division")

while True:
    try:
        a=float(input("input the first number: "))
    except:
        print ("try again")

    else:
        break
        pass

while True:
    try:
        b=float(input("input the second number: "))
    except:
        print ("try again")

    else:
        break
print ("Your final answer is: ", a/b)
```

EDIT: sorry this is my very first question. I am not sure how to correctly format the code portion of the question. I have tried for about 20 minutes of which lead to failure and a good amount of frustration.

EDIT2: thank you for the comments. Finally figured out how to format the question, but still needs an answer.

Comment: Delete the whole code portion, then try again: paste it, then highlight all of it, and click the formatting button that looks like {} to indicate that it's code.

Comment: Also note that on Stack Overflow (Markdown), every line in a block of code starts off with 4 spaces

Comment: The code does work for me. What exactly is your problem? What’s not working?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick refactoring of this code that shows how you can (A) not repeat yourself, and (B) use slightly more descriptive variable names:

```
def get_input(prompt):

    # Get a number from the user.

    while True:
        try:
            answer = float(input(prompt))
            return answer
        except ValueError:
            print ("try again")

def main():
    print ("We're gonna be doing some division")
    numerator = get_input("Input the first number: ")
    denominator = get_input("Input the second number: ")
    print ("Your final answer is: ", numerator/denominator)

main()
```

Comment: You should `except ValueError` so you don't catch other problems by mistake. In general, it's a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I can tell, the logic is correct in your program except for this: You don't need the `pass` keyword. Instead, break from the while loop when the input is correct. Also, try making sure that all of the white space is as intended. If I understand correctly, you want something like this:

```
a = 0.0
b = 0.0

print("We're going to do some division")
while True:
    try:
        a = float(input("Enter first number: "))
        break
    except:
        print("try again")

while True:
    try:
        b = float(input("Enter second number: "))
        break
    except:
        print("try again")

print("The answer is: " + str(a / b))
```